# Put (paste) character-wise yanked text over block-wise visual selection

Tags: vim, vi, paste

Is there a way to easily achieve the above?

For e.g., given

```
red apple
red banana
red cucumber

The fruits are blue.
```

Is there a way for me to yank the word "blue", then visually-select the column of "red" words and paste so that we get:

```
blue apple
blue banana
blue cucumber.

The words are blue.
```

Right now, the first "red" gets replaced and the remaining get cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `red` column is selected, do the following:

```
c         " change
<C-r>0    " Ctrl+r followed by 0 inserts the last yanked text (from register 0)
<Esc>     " exit insert mode and apply change to the whole column
```

Answer (score 1):

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) will allow that. Select the block of `red`, then press `gr`. All words will be replaced by the previously yanked `blue`, plus the unnamed register continues to hold `blue`.